# change standard background color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a calendar on my site where the user can select a time range. I'm using the react-advanced-datetimerange-picker library for this, but I'm changing the library's default styles and ran into a problem.

I would like to change the background color in the box that I marked with a red arrow in the photo below. I also took a screenshot of the developer panel so you can see the styles and markup.

It seems like an easy task, but I've tried many options with no success.

[image]

What do I need to write in my .css file so that I can change the background color?

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-khorana-gbjuiz

Comment: "*I also took a screenshot of the developer panel so you can see the styles and markup*" - it would have been so much easier (and of for more use) had you posted the relevant "*[mcve]*" code as textual code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the **background** from **#FFFFFF** to any color you want!

There are many methods to achieve that

As seen in the screenshot
The input has a class **inputDate**

> First Method

**
Assuming u want to set the **background** color to **orange**.

```
.inputDate{
   background: Orange;
}
```

> Another method:

You can use inline styling by adding **style="background: orange"** to the input

```
<input style="background: orange" class="inputDate"..... />
```